# AWK one-liner to process a file having different number of fields

Tags: linux, awk

What I'm trying to do is create a little script actually I know it is possible to make it a one-liner. I have a large file containing different number of fields. And what I want to do is sum the last field in each record if it is a number with a decimal point... And to print the result with the printf with a placeholder "%f\n"...

Comment: What *specific* aspect of the task are you having trouble with? you can access the last field using `$NF`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the $NF. But, that was my bad, I was not clear enough. That is the part I am stuck on. I know I can access the last field using $NF but I can't make them to sum up. And I can't state that I want to sum only the ones with a decimal point.

Comment: Well, awk programs are based on rules and actions: so presumably you want a rule that matches records whose last field contains a decimal point - depending what your data look like, that might be something as simple as `$NF ~ /\./` (or `$NF ~ /,/` depending on your locale) or might need to be as complex as a [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum the last fields that have a decimal comma (dot) in them:

```
awk '$NF ~ /\./ { sum += $NF } END { printf("%f\n", sum ) }' file.in
```

That is, if the data in the last field (`$NF`) has a dot in it, assume that it's a number and add it to `sum`.  At the end, print the sum with the format specified in the question.

Note that this will skip any integers in the last field.

The following will allow `awk` to try to use the last field as a number regardless of what it actually is.  This means that `1` will be interpreted as 1 and that `1.2` will be interpreted as 1.2.  The strings `hello` and `boo` will be zero while `123abc` will be taken as 123.

```
awk '{ sum += $NF } END { printf("%f\n", sum) }'
```

The following will not sum fields that contain anything other than digits, dots, pluses and minuses:

```
awk '$NF ~ /^[-+0-9.]*$/ { sum += $NF } END { printf("%f\n", sum) }'
```

It will still accept `09+99...` (as 9), but matching floating point numbers is non-trivial and depends on the format you would need to match.  See e.g. [these examples at RegExLib site](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=float) for more useful patterns.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed! Appreciate your help!